# mkdir() is not creating the new directory

Tags: java, file-handling

I am using Eclipse and jdk1.7. I am making a basic program using file handling, in which an output directory inside the directory is to be made. But when I run the program, the output is showing false and the directory is not made. I thought that the output was false because of the presence of a directory with the same name, but this is not the reason. So I need help. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;

public class P {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f1 = new File ("abc");
        File f2 = new File (f1,"abc");
        System.out.println(f2.mkdir());
    }
}
```

Its output is false and yet no directory has been created.
How can I resolve this problem? This is not only in  this program - each and every program in which I am calling the method `mkdir()` is having the same problem.

Comment: does "abc"  exist and is a directory? did you look for the new directory in the working directory of your program? (print new  File("").getAbsolutePath() to find out the WD)

Comment: For diagnostics, print [`f2.getAbsolutPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()). Maybe its trying to create the directories in a location where you don't have write access?

Comment: Java 7 introduced the Files class that uses exceptions instead of boolean return values.  This can be useful for getting a text description of what failed for future debugging.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have to use [mkdirs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) with an s if you want to create multiple directories. It is probably also worth checking that you [canWrite()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canWrite%28%29) to the location as some places are permissioned. Both of these are on the File class

Answer (score 21):

its `obj.mkdirs()`

have a look to this:

```
File  f = new File("non_existing_dir/someDir");
System.out.println(f.mkdir());
System.out.println(f.mkdirs());
```

The first print won't create a directory and returns `false` but the second does and returns `true`

Comment: Still, it is not able to create a directory from the f.mkdirs() function. It is returning false.

Answer (score 0):

[Create directory example](http://www.java-examples.com/create-directory)

it looks like you'll need to work on your path a bit as it doesn't look like File will infer "abc."

Also, make sure you have permissions on the path you're attempting to create the directory. If you don't, it will fail. It has been a while since I've played with Java, so not sure if you'd need to do mkdir calls the entire way down the path (ie /here/, /here/now-here/, /here/now-here/final) or not. Think it may be recursive but that'd be worth verifying.

Actually, from looking at the other answers looks like mkdirs would be recursive, mkdir is not. I'd go with mkdirs especially if the input isn't going to be known from the onset otherwise you'll end up writing a function with mkdir that does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

calling the only `file.mkdirs()` often doesn't work.
call it in an evaluation such as -

```
if(file.mkdirs()){ //do something}
```

Or,
 in an assignment such as -

```
 boolean result = file.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure there are no dots in the directory name. For example: "ab.c"should be changed to "abc".

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? If so, I wasn't able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Use
Files.createDirectory(Paths.get(strTempNewDirPath));
instead of mkdir().

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

mkdir needs the abstract path, not the relative path. try to use...

```
File f2 = new File (f1, "C:\\");
```

... for example.

**From Java DOC:**

> public boolean mkdir()
>
> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname.
>
> Returns:
>
> true if and only if the directory was created; false otherwise
>
> Throws:
>
> SecurityException - If a security manager exists and its SecurityManager.checkWrite(java.lang.String) method does not permit the named directory to be created